# Leaking axle bearings

Tags: axle, seal

In my Bronco, the 9" rear axle has the tapered roller bearings and has started leaking. With these bearings (Timken Set 20) is there supposed to be an inner axle seal? I have just been using the ones that came with the bearings that go on the outside of the bearing. Also, should the oil level be high enough that some runs down the tubes to the bearings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...is there supposed to be an inner axle seal?

No

> should the oil level be high enough that some runs down the tubes to
>   the bearings?

Yes, that's what keep those bearings lubricated.

Comment: I replaced the bearings and seals about a year ago. What could cause the seals to fail this soon?

Comment: Cheap seals, installed slightly off/pinched or overheating because the bearing didn't get enough lubrication would come to mind.

Comment: Do you think they sell just the seals? Mine came with the bearings.

Comment: @Jaime yes you can get only the seals.